# How to sort results from MongoTemplate.findAll()?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I currently have a query that returns all the documents in a collection using the findAll() method of MongoTemplate.  I want to sort these results, but do not see any way to do so.  I see that I can use find() with a Query argument and call .with(Sort sort), but in this scenario, how do I set the Query to return all documents?  I would be okay with using either approach.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59060633/the-constructor-sortsort-direction-string-is-undefined

Answer (score 11):

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));

List<MyClass> myClassList=  mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: This is initially what I tried, but for some reason, I just get an empty list back.

Comment: The method "with" returns a Query object, so: query = query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));

Comment: This may have changed in recent versions, but `Sort`'s constructor is (now) private. My field was different, but I used `Sort.by("_id").descending()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

An empty Query will behave as findAll(). Like you can write in the mongo shell: db.myCollection.find({}) you can write an emypty Query in the java mongdb driver.

An working sample code would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
{
    ServerAddress address = new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(address);
    SimpleMongoDbFactory simpleMongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(client, "mydatabase");
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(simpleMongoDbFactory);
    Query query = new Query().with(new Sort("_id", "-1"));
    List<MyClass> allObjects = mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class);
    System.out.println(allObjects);
}
```

Comment: This is initially what I tried, but for some reason, I just get an empty list back.

Comment: How come you're able to try that. I'm not able to use this solution at all. Reason: private Sort(Direction direction, List<String> properties)

Comment: well, my answer is five years old. The api has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is now:

```js
Query query = new Query();
query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));

List<MyClass> myClassList=  mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass.class);
```