# The constructor Sort(Sort.Direction, String) is undefined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to use Spring Data JPA with default sort direction with the latest spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.1.RELEASE:

```
@Override
public Page<ProcessingLogs> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page,size, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt")));
}
```

But I get error:

```
The constructor Sort(Sort.Direction, String) is undefined
```

This is the latest code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.java

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You linked the source, did you even take a look at it? `Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdAt");`.

Comment: ... I have to change `new Sort` to `Sort.by`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use like this `PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"createdAt"))`

Comment: Just to expand. The constructor was removed and statics 'Sort.by(direction, properties)' is used in place.